# Dart Async Does Not Wait for Completion

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-async

I'm currently trying to wait for a BLE connection to result in one of two outcomes:

- Device connected successfully, or
- Device failed to connect after the scan timed out

Instead of returning a true or false value as desired, null is immediately returned, without waiting for the function to finish.

I'm using dart's Future and async functionality in order to wait for the completion of the connect function. Here is my code below:

BLE Connect method:

```
    static Future<bool> connect(BluetoothDevice d) async {
    // Connect to device
    Duration timeout = new Duration(seconds: 5);

    deviceConnection = _flutterBlue.connect(d, timeout: timeout).listen((s) {
      deviceState = s;
      if (s == BluetoothDeviceState.connected) {
        device = d;

        device.discoverServices().then((s) {
          ... Some service discovery stuff ...
        });
      }
    }, onDone: () {
      return deviceState == BluetoothDeviceState.connected;
    });
  }
```

Where the connect method is being called from:

```
bool isConnected = await FlutterBLE.connect(device);

if(isConnected) {
    ... Do some stuff ...
} else {
    ... Do some other stuff ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Günther Zöchbauer has pointed out, the mistake is in the `onDone` part. You are returning a value there that nobody will ever see, and you are no returning anything from the surrounding function.

You are inside an async function, so you can use `await for` to iterate the stream.
You also want to stop listening to the stream the first time you get a connection event, because you only care about the first connection. The stream of connection events itself never stops.

```
static Future<bool> connect(BluetoothDevice d) async {
  // Connect to device
  Duration timeout = const Duration(seconds: 5);

  await for (var s in _flutterBlue.connect(d, timeout: timeout)) {
    deviceState = s;
    if (s == BluetoothDeviceState.connected) {
      device = d;

      device.discoverServices().then((s) {
        ... Some service discovery stuff ...
      });
      return true;
    }
  }
  // The stream ended somehow, there will be no further events.
  return false;
}
```

If you don't want to use `await for` (and not using an async function to begin with), I would recommend using `firstWhere` to find the first connection (if any) over `listen`:

```
static Future<bool> connect(BluetoothDevice d) {
  // Connect to device
  Duration timeout = const Duration(seconds: 5);

  return _flutterBlue.connect(d, timeout: timeout).firstWhere((s) {
    return s == BluetoothDeviceState.connected;
  }, orElse: () => null).then((s) {
    if (s == null) return false;
    deviceState = s;
    device = d;
    device.discoverServices().then((s) {
      //... Some service discovery stuff ...
    });
    return true;
  });
```

It's also slightly suspicious that nobody waits for the future returned by `device.discoverServices().then(...)`. Make sure that this is correct.

Comment: Irn,

I have tried your first solution (I want to keep this function async), and it doesn't seem to work for me. Like Gunther's solution, the function does not return true on a successful connection, it instead never returns a value. Also like Gunther's solution, when the Duration times out, the correct value is returned (false).

Comment: I have no idea what the code *means*, so this is just guessing: Do you want to stop listening when the first `s == BlutoothDeviceState.connected` succeeds? If so, add a `break` at the end of the `if`'s body. That will break out of the loop.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I'll admit that I'm fairly confused - the placement of the break makes sense to me, but the fact that the method never returned a value confuses me. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You are listening on a stream of connection events, and that listening only stops when either the stream is done or you stop listening. I'm guessing the stream is never closed (the blue-tooth device never stops listening for connections), so you have to stop listening by exiting the `await for` loop. I'll update the example code.

Answer (score 0):

The `onDone` part doesn't do what you expect.
Try instead:

```
static Future<bool> connect(BluetoothDevice d) async {
// Connect to device
Duration timeout = new Duration(seconds: 5);

await _flutterBlue.connect(d, timeout: timeout).listen((s) {
  deviceState = s;
  if (s == BluetoothDeviceState.connected) {
    device = d;

    device.discoverServices().then((s) {
      ... Some service discovery stuff ...
    });
  }
}).asFuture();
return deviceState == BluetoothDeviceState.connected;
}
```

Comment: Günter, 

I've attempted your solution in my code, and it does not seem to work all the time, I'm assuming this is becuase of another misunderstanding on my part.

If the device fails to connect this solution works beautifully, the Duration times out and the method returns false, just as planned. However, when the device successfully connects, the function never returns, I never get a bool value back from the function, as I have methods to check for the return value. What could be the issue?

Comment: Have you checked lrn's approach as well?

Comment: Yes I have, and his approach results in the same outcome. Why could the function be "hanging" like that?

Comment: I don't know flutterBlue. Perhaps `_flutterBlue.connect(d, timeout: timeout).` never completes the stream. You could try `.first` instead of `asFuture()`